# REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL extract "search operators" in a query

Tags: sql, regex, google-bigquery

I'm trying to use BigQuery's [REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/string_functions#regexp_extract_all) function to parse "search queries" of the form *operator: query*. There can be multiple operator/query pairs in a query string, and the "subquery" that falls under an operator can have multiple words enclosed by parens. I'd like to extract only the "search operators" from the query string using a regular expression.

For example:

- *animal: cat* -> ["animal"]
- *animal: (mountain lion)* -> ["animal"]
- *month: february day: sunday* -> ["month", "day"]
- *date: (july 31) weather: (blue sky)* -> ["date", "weather"]

Any suggestions? I'm definitely a regex noob, the best I've done so far is

`REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(query, "(.\*):") AS operator`

which recursively expands all of the text seen before colons (giving me results like ["date", "date: (july 31) weather"]).

One last "advanced" feature I'd like to implement is only including search operators if they are fully made up of text. For example:
*time: 2020-07-08T17:09:14.043Z* -> ["time"]

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```golang
regexp_extract_all(query, r'\b([a-zA-Z]+):') AS operator
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/Ar0TQK/1).

**Explanation**

```golang
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w) and
                           something that is not a word char
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [a-zA-Z]+                any character of: 'a' to 'z', 'A' to 'Z'
                             (1 or more times (matching the most
                             amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  :                        ':'
```

Answer (score 2):

Try below

```
regexp_extract_all(query, r'([^: ]+):') AS operator
```

if to apply to sample data in your question - output is

[image]